# How can I define a full tab in an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to split a large angular component containing a `<mat-tab-group>` and several `<mat-tab>`into :

- a parent component defining the `<mat-tab-group>`
- children components each defining their own `<mat-tab>`

The template for the parent looks like:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <child-component1></child-component1>
  <child-component2></child-component2>
  <child-component3></child-component3>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And each child looks like:

```html
<mat-tab>
  ...
</mat-tab>
```

The children are properly initialized without errors, however they are not rendered to the DOM. It works as expected if I put every `<mat-tab>` in the parent, and have only the tab content in the children components.

This is not a proper solution to my problem though: given that the children components need to render the tab label, it doesn't seem right to let the parent responsible of that.

My understanding is that a `<mat-tab>` element must be a direct child of the `<mat-tab-group>` to be properly rendered and that my `<child-component>`s prevent that.

What would be the best way to have the `<mat-tab>` defined in the children components?

Comment: can you please provide a Stackblitz solution ?

Comment: Exactly, <mat-tab> element must be a direct child of the <mat-tab-group> to be properly rendered. What if you add mat-tab as a direct child and add your component inside it?

Comment: @dhanushkac that's what I will do if I don't find another way, but the label of the tab is dependent of the child component behavior, so I would prefer to have the label rendered in the child instead of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make tab list base on your ViewModel and then do like this:

```
 <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="tabIndex">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab.Title">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span> {{tab.Title}}</span>
      </ng-template>
      <dynamic-content [TabComponent]="tab"></dynamic-content>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

Then call your component base on Tab Item click , In fact use dynamic component.